# How to dismiss the dialog only not the activity which calling that dialog on press of back key?

Tags: android

I am populating a dialog which is having a tab view from an activity. Tab view start different activity on clicking different tab with the help of different intent. If i press back key, activity which is calling dialog is also getting dismissed with dialog. But on press of back key i just wnat to dismiss the dialog not the calling activity. how to do that?

Comment: This should be done by default do you override onKeyPressed? If so show teh codez!

Comment: This is not the standard behavior. Do you have a key listener or something?

Answer (score 1):

Override the `setOnCancelListener` of the dialog or the activity `onBackPressed` depending on your application. Post your code for more accurate awnsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `dialog.dismiss()` method.

Answer (score 1):

there is a default method present in android 2.1 and above called onBackButtonPressed(). it is a part of the activity class.... so in that method just do the following:

dialog.dismiss();

this will not do anything else.. but just close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Venues", "Loading...", true, true,     new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } );
```